# How to use CNTK classification_error()?

Tags: cntk

I am trying to understand the correct usage of `cntk.metrics.classification_error()` and use it to verify a batch of predictions against their ground truths.

The below toy example (based on the [Python API docs](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.metrics.html#cntk.metrics.classification_error)):

```
import numpy as np
from cntk.metrics import classification_error

predictions = np.asarray([[1., 2., 3., 4.],[1., 2., 3., 4.],[1., 2., 3., 4.]], dtype=np.float32)
labels = np.asarray([[0., 0., 0., 1.],[0., 0., 0., 1.],[0., 0., 1., 0.]], dtype=np.float32)
classification_error(predictions, labels).eval()
```

yields the following result:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Is there a way I can obtain a vector rather than a square matrix which appears inefficient given I would like to process a large batch?

I've tried using the `axis` keyword when calling `classification_error()`, but whether I set `axis=0` or `axis=1` I get an empty result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because CNTK is trying to be user-friendly and ends up being confused about the types :-) You can tell because the classification error is not even correct.

If you add a little bit of typing information it gets the semantics right.

```
p = C.input(4)
y = C.input(4)
classification_error(p, y).eval({p:predictions, y:labels})
array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

We will work on a fix that will prevent the confusion.

Comment: Thank you! I should have thought to create inputs for the function, but it didn't cross my mind as the example in the docs didn't make that explicit.